# How to deserialize php array in node js or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, serialization

I want to deserialize data from php serialize array in node js

I found in many questions use JSON.stringify() to serialize and for deserialize use JSON.parse but unable to do the same and not find any solution for the same too

My serialize data:-

```
a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:10:"first_name";s:7:"Vikas";s:11:"last_name";s:6:"Kohli";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"2017-06-12";s:16:"position";s:19:"Software Developer";}}
```

How to deserialize this array ?

I found to slove the same using

1. http://locutus.io/php/var/unserialize/ but I didn't saw any implementation for the same.
2. https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize --- ( Compatibility issues -This library has been tested server-side only. For example it uses [].reduce, so it may not work on some browsers. Do not hesitate to make pull requests to fix it for you favorite browsers :) that's why not used

Also when I used the second method, then it results like

```
{ '0': 
   { first_name: 'Vikas',
     last_name: '899.99',
     end_date: '2017-06-12',
     position: 'Software Developer' 
    }
}
```

Now how would I fetch the data from that if I used as there can be data like 0, 1 ,2 and so on

I hope I am able to understand my question.

Comment: What's the use case here? Can you simply use json_encode instead of serialize?

Comment: well, just a simple google whould show this **[javascript php deserialize](https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize)** library.

Comment: Please show the PHP code with which you produce this. There are certainly better ways to do this than to try to decode this in JavaScript.

Comment: *"I hope I am able to understand my question."*: fingers crossed.

Comment: @trincot In php, deserialize like this $data11=unserialize(($row['data']));

Comment: @mkaatman Actually some other guy do that so that's why want to deserialize.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg updated the question for that too